# Django development server seems to be using old version of python source file

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm re-writing the code of my website, and testing with Django's built-in web server using the `manage.py runserver` command. Now I've come across a very strange problem: The server seems to use the current version of `views.py` on the very first page load, but all subsequent refreshes give me a server error because the server is apperently using an older version of `views.py`, but the current versions of all other files, which leads to errors – specifically URL resolver errors, because I changed some code from using hard-coded paths in `views.py` to using the URL resolver, which of course doesn't work if the URL resolver receives a *path* (from the old `views.py`) when it's expecting a view name (which I put in the new `views.py`).

I have already deleted all the `.pyc` files in my django project directory and rebooted the machine, to no avail. The problem persists.

I'm using Django 1.7.6 on Python 3.4.2.

Here's the current `views.py` (it doesn't really make sense, it's just for testing):

```
from mezgrman.utils import NavigationTemplateResponse

NAV_DATA = {
    'app_root': 'index',
    'app_title': "Item Manager",
    'navbar': [
        ("Add Item", 'index'),
    ],
    'page_title': "Item Manager",
}

def index(request):
    return NavigationTemplateResponse(request, "design_test/index.html", NAV_DATA)
```

The `NavigationTemplateResponse` is a subclass of `TemplateResponse`:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, reverse

class NavigationTemplateResponse(TemplateResponse):
    def __init__(self, request, template, nav_data, context = None, content_type = None, status = None, current_app = None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}

        url_name = resolve(request.path).url_name
        app_name = url_name.split(".")[0]
        view_prefix = app_name + ".views."

        nav_data['app_root'] = reverse(view_prefix + nav_data.get('app_root', ""))

        for index, entry in enumerate(nav_data.get('navbar', [])):
            title, view_name = entry
            nav_data['navbar'][index] = (title, reverse(view_prefix + view_name))

        context.update(nav_data)
        return super().__init__(request, template, context, content_type, status, current_app)
```

The Django server traceback explicitly proves that it's using an old version of `views.py`, these are the local variables (sans the `WSGIRequest`) at the time of the error, where `nav_data` is the same as in the old `views.py`:

```
content_type        None
template            'design_test/index.html'
url_name            'design_test.views.index'
status              None
self                <mezgrman.utils.NavigationTemplateResponse object at 0x7f395f8d15f8>
app_name            'design_test'
__class__           <class 'mezgrman.utils.NavigationTemplateResponse'>
context             {}
view_prefix         'design_test.views.'
current_app         None
nav_data            {
                        'app_root': '/',
                        'app_title': 'Item Manager',
                        'navbar': [('Add Item', '/')],
                        'page_title': 'Item Manager'
                    }
```

This seems to me like a bug in Django, but I'd like to know if there's another reason for this strange behaviour. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bug, and also this is not old code of `views.py`. You're simply overwriting your data in NAV_DATA inside your view. In first request from starting server NAV_DATA have it's initial values, but on that request you're overriding some values with reversed urls. That change persists between requests until dev server is reloaded.

**Solution 1:** work on copy of your dict:

```
class NavigationTemplateResponse(TemplateResponse):
    def __init__(self, request, template, nav_data, context = None, content_type = None, status = None, current_app = None):
        nav_data = nav_data.copy()
```

**Solution 2:** change your logic to store reversed urls in other variables

**Solution 3:** change your logic to behave differently when urls are already reversed. That solution is **not** thread safe!

Comment: Thank you! Of course, I understand. I know that dictionaries behave this way, but somehow I thought when I passed the dictionary as a parameter it would get copied. It's obvious now! Also, your answer made me realize I don't need to lookup the URLs on every page load, but only once. Thanks a lot!